# How can I resume to show the preorder bst?

Tags: java

In my preious version of random to generate some value to array of node, it will be export the number of nodes and show the result after using BST. Then, my question is after I added scanner to input value by manually, it can't export the nodes with postorder now.

Before :

```
    Inserting 9 nodes:
    80 65 74 90 32 30 57 31 41
    BST - size: 9 height: 4
    30 31 32 41 57 65 74 80 90
```

After added insert :

```
Enter the number of the data: 5
Enter the values:
4
36
42
12
34
Inserted: [4, 36, 42, 12, 34]
It used postorder.
BinarySearchTree - size: 1 height: 0
trees.BSTree@30dae81
5
```

I expect:

```
Enter the number of the data: 5
    Enter the values:
    4
    36
    42
    12
    34
    Inserted: [4, 36, 42, 12, 34]
    It used postorder.
    BinarySearchTree - size: $sizevalue height: $heightvalue
    [4, 12, 34, 36, 42]
```

May I know did I need to change the tree and node?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the question. Are you asking how you can print your `int[] data` without getting something like `[I@5b6f7412` ?

Comment: try to write: `System.out.print(data + " ");` as `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data));`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: now my preoder function not work.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS

please see my new comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo:

replace `tree.insert(input);` with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = sc.nextInt();
    tree.insert(data[i]);
}
```

**P.S.** Preorder traversal will not give you expected output: sorted list. [Tree Traversals (Inorder, Preorder and Postorder)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/)

---

```
public final class BinarySearchTree {

    private Node root;
    private int size;

    public void add(int val) {
        root = add(root, new Node(val));
        size++;
    }

    private static Node add(Node parent, Node node) {
        if (parent == null)
            return node;
        if (node.val < parent.val)
            parent.left = add(parent.left, node);
        else
            parent.right = add(parent.right, node);
        return parent;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public boolean find(int val) {
        return dfsFind(root, val);
    }

    private static boolean dfsFind(Node node, int val) {
        if (node == null)
            return false;
        if (node.val == val)
            return true;
        return dfsFind(node.left, val) || dfsFind(node.right, val);
    }

    public int[] getTraversals(Traversals traversals) {
        int[] arr = new int[size];
        traversals.print(root, arr, 0);
        return arr;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public int height() {
        return dfsHeight(root, 1);
    }

    private static int dfsHeight(Node node, int depth) {
        if (node == null)
            return depth - 1;
        return Math.max(dfsHeight(node.left, depth + 1), dfsHeight(node.right, depth + 1));
    }

    public enum Traversals {
        INORDER {
            @Override
            protected int print(Node node, int[] arr, int i) {
                if (node != null) {
                    i = print(node.left, arr, i);
                    arr[i++] = node.val;
                    i = print(node.right, arr, i);
                }

                return i;
            }
        },
        PREORDER {
            @Override
            int print(Node node, int[] arr, int i) {
                if (node != null) {
                    arr[i++] = node.val;
                    i = print(node.left, arr, i);
                    i = print(node.right, arr, i);
                }

                return i;
            }
        },
        POSTORDER {
            @Override
            int print(Node node, int[] arr, int i) {
                if (node != null) {
                    i = print(node.left, arr, i);
                    i = print(node.right, arr, i);
                    arr[i++] = node.val;
                }

                return i;
            }
        };

        abstract int print(Node node, int[] arr, int i);
    }

    private static final class Node {

        private final int val;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;

        public Node(int val) {
            this.val = val;
            left = right = null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(val);
        }

    }

}
```

---

**Demo:**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the number of the data: ");
int total = scan.nextInt();
int[] data = new int[total];

BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
System.out.println("Enter the values: ");

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    System.out.format("%d: ", i);
    data[i] = scan.nextInt();
    tree.add(data[i]);
}

System.out.print("Inserted: ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));

System.out.println("BinarySearchTree - size: " + tree.size() + " height: " + tree.height());

System.out.println("Inorder: " + Arrays.toString(tree.getTraversals(BinarySearchTree.Traversals.INORDER)));
System.out.println("Preorder: " + Arrays.toString(tree.getTraversals(BinarySearchTree.Traversals.PREORDER)));
System.out.println("Postorder: " + Arrays.toString(tree.getTraversals(BinarySearchTree.Traversals.POSTORDER)));
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the number of the data: 5
Enter the values: 
0: 4
1: 36
2: 42
3: 12
4: 34
Inserted: [4, 36, 42, 12, 34]
BinarySearchTree - size: 5 height: 4
Inorder: [4, 12, 34, 36, 42]
Preorder: [4, 36, 12, 34, 42]
Postorder: [34, 12, 42, 36, 4]
```

Comment: can I ask some question on it? May I know method dfsFind and getTraversals doing?

Answer (score 0):

to print the values of `data` either you need to iterate through the values using a for loop and print or you need to use `Arrays class`:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data) + " ");
```

Comment: hi please see my below comment

Comment: @erictc what do you mean??

Comment: I have added a answer on below. can you please help to find my postorder is only show 5 now.

Comment: @erictc what do you mean by 5 and where do you want the 5 be printed, and you didn't share the code of `tree.postorder();`

Comment: @erictc where do want the 5 to be printed please add your expected output

Comment: Yes, sure. I have updated my expect output on main post